# Creating a self-affine fractal on L-systems

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, programming-languages, recursion

Hi I would like to create a self-affine fractal on L-Systems.
The axiom I have created is FF-GGG-GG-GGG++GGG+GG-GGG+GG+GGG+FF++ffGG+GGG+FF+GGG which creates the image below

At each stage I would like to replace each rectangle with the initial pattern. I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Try generalizing the Sierpinski triangle example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, here. If you're asking how to use some piece of software, that's off-topic here; if you're not, then it looks more like pure mathematics than computer science, to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am asking for help with using a piece of software yes. Is that off topic for cs exchange? Where should I ask it?

Comment: Specific implementations are off-topic here, yes: we deal with general scientific principles (e.g., algorithms) rather than specific expressions of those principles (e.g., coding). Perhaps [su] is the right place? ("How do I convince this piece of software to do what I want?") But be sure to link to the software and so on so they can see that it's a question about software, not about mathematics.